# Error al ingresar al launcher de Anaconda spyder 1>nul 2>nul

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Lo he estado haciendo sin problemas por un tiempo, instalando paquetes, actualizando paquetes / Spyder, pero después de actualizar Spyder, ahora recibo un mensaje de error al iniciar Spyder desde Anaconda.

C:\Users\carit>chcp 1252
Página de códigos activa: 1252

C:\Users\carit>call C:\Users\carit\anaconda3\Scripts\activate C:\Users\carit\anaconda3

(base) C:\Users\carit>spyder  1>nul 2>nul

Esta ventana de terminal aparece, luego se cierra y Spyder junto con ella.

Si abro una ventana de terminal desde Anaconda y spyder escribo, puedo iniciar la aplicación con éxito. Pero el lanzamiento desde Anaconda Navigator falla, y no entiendo este mensaje de error o cómo solucionarlo, ni he podido encontrar nada relacionado con este problema en la búsqueda. Se agradecería cualquier ayuda para comprender lo que está sucediendo y cómo corregirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba desde Anaconda Navigator lo siguiente:

File >> Preferences >> Configure Conda >> Reset to defaults
File >> Preferences >> Configure Navigator >> Reset to defaults